# If a module over a group ring has no self-extensions, can it have any self-extension over subgroups?

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I use the terminology of K.S. Brown's "Cohomology of groups". Let $RG$ be the group ring formed by an arbitrary group $G$ over a commutative ring  $R$, and let $X$ be a finitely generated left $RG$-module satisfying $Ext^i_{RG}(X, X)=0$ for $i\geq 1$. Let also $H\leq G$ be a subgroup of finite index. If I assume further that $RG$ is left Noetherian, then I want to know if $Ext^i_{RH}(X, X)=0$ holds (We know $X$ is an $RH$-module by restriction). I have tried the following:

Assume for a moment that $X$ is $RG-RG$-bimodule. Then since $RG$ is $RH$-free and $RG\otimes_{RH} X$ is finitely generated,
\begin{eqnarray*}
Ext^i_{RG}(RG\otimes_{RH} X, RG\otimes_{RH} X) &\simeq& RG\otimes_{RH} Ext^i_{RG}(RG\otimes_{RH} X, X)\\
&\simeq& RG\otimes_{RH} Ext^i_{RG}(Hom_{RH}(RG, X), X)
\end{eqnarray*}
where I use that $RG\otimes_{RH} X\simeq Hom_{RH}(RG, X)$ (with the structures inherited from $RG$) because $H$ is of finite index. But by using an injective resolution of $X$, I use, e.g. Theorem 3.2.11 in Enochs's "Relative homological algebra" to get that $Ext^i_{RG} (Hom_{RH}(RG, X), X)$ is isomorphic to $RG\otimes_{RH} Ext^i_{RG}(X,X)=0$. So now $Ext^i_{RG}(RG\otimes_{RH} X, RG\otimes_{RH} X)$ vanishes and I use Eckmann-Shapiro's lemma to deduce that $Ext^i_{RH}(X, X)=0$.

Unfortunately this argument seems to work only for bimodules. I want to know if there is a way to
omit this extra hypothesis and obtain the same result for every left $RG$-module $X$. I warmly thank any comments.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused as to how "$X$ is a bimodule" can be helpful : any $RG$-module can be a made into an $RG-$bimodule by stipulating that the right $G$-action is trivial (as $R$ is commutative, you can also define $x\cdot r := rx$)

Comment: Thank you Maxim for the comment. You are right about imposing bimodule structure via the trivial G-action. However, I'm suspicious about validity of the isomorphisms mentioned in the question, because all the structures have been induced in a natural way.  Particularly, does the isomorphism $Ext^i_{RG} (Hom_{RH}(RG, X) , X) \simeq RG\otimes_{RH}Ext^i_{RG}(X, X) $ still hold with this hypothesis? This was used in the last line of the proof and this is where I mostly require the bimodule structure (to make $Ext^i_{RG}(X, X)$ into an RH-left module).

Comment: I do agree that this isomorphism seems suspect. I should also point out that the Shapiro-lemma only has one $RG$, namely $Ext^i_{RH}(X,X) \cong Ext^i_{RG}(RG\otimes_{RH}X, X)$. I don't know the answer to the original question, though I would guess that this is not true if I had to guess

Comment: When you say "for $i\geqslant 1$" do you mean for some particular $i\geqslant 1$, or for all $i\geqslant 1$?

Comment: I mean for every $i\geq 1$ both for the hypothesis and the assertion.